# Unable to import xlrd module

Tags: python, xlrd, cx-freeze

Few of the packages  which my executable script is using are dependent on xlrd module. So I tried to include this module in the setup script by using the include option as shown. But when the runnery.py gives call to package modules, the module is not able to import xlrd though xlrd file are present in the library.zip file.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import xlrd

buildOptions = dict(
                compressed = True,
                optimize=2,
                path=sys.path+[".\\uitls", “.\\supported”],
include_files=[“Doc"],
                includes=[“xlrd”, "win32com"],
                packages=["utils", ”supported"],
                append_script_to_exe=True,
                copy_dependent_files=True,
                 )
setup(
                name = "TestExecutable",
                version = "0.1",
                options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
                          executables = [Executable(
                                         script=r".\\codebase\\ runner.py",
                                         icon=".\\icon.ico",
                                         base="Win32GUI")]
                )
```

Whereas if I try to import the xlrd in the runner.py, it is being able to import it. I not sure what is going wrong in this case, as the dependent packages are not being able to import xlrd.  Is there some option that I am missing or something that I am doing wrong?

Update: 
I found that the dependent package is called by spawning a process, so it creates a new environment, which do not have the xlrd module loded into it and is not aware of the library.zip containing it. So now, is it somehow possible for me to make the xlrd module available to the package from the zip file even if it ran by spwaning new process?
Regards,

Comment: Note that your "code" contains MS Word open/close quote characters ... compare xlrd with win32com in `includes=[“xlrd”, "win32com"],` ... Please show the code that you actually ran; don't edit it and don't type it from memory.

Comment: What spawns the new process? runner.py? What is the name of the exe file created by your setup.py? What is the name of the exe file that is spawned?

Answer (score 3):

When you download the xlrd package, you have two choices:

1. Include `xlrd-0.7.1\xlrd\` in  your Python Path.
2. Install it `python xlrd-0.7.1\setup.py install`

Once your done (either one). Verify that you can import it. Open up python and just type `import xlrd`. If you see no error, you know it has successfully installed.

Comment: xlrd is successfully installed on my machine and the code works well when not packaged using xlrd...the problem arises only when i pack it using cx_freeze

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the `uitls` in `path=sys.path+[".\\uitls", “.\\supported”],` should be `utils`.

Where exactly has xlrd been installed?

`xlrd` is a package, not a module; have you tried putting it in the packages list instead of the includes list?

Use raw strings consistently.

Why do you have doubled backslashes in `script=r".\\codebase\\ runner.py",` ? Windows appears to regard multiple backslashes as one, but why chance it?? Why do you have a space before `runner.py`? Are you sure that this setup file actually runs?

Comment: hi,I cleaned the setup.py file as you suggested and added the xlrd to the packages option but still the error persists. The space in the runner.py actually occured by mistake as i was in process of cleaning up the script for posting it :)

Answer (score 2):

Found a work around for the problem
I copied the xlrd folder form the lib\site-packages folder and included it under include_files option. Now when my subprocess executable is run, the path is set, so it knows the location of xlrd and the executable is able to import xlrd.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the xlrd module was not properly installed. You can install from the command prompt in Windows pip install xlrd, and this should fix your issue. I ran into the same issue when utilizing Pandas to read files with the extension xlsx.